# Set components' visibility based on global state

Tags: game, react.js, jsx, redux

I'm building a game interface that has the following user flow:

The user lands on one of the game's URLs (eg. `www.name.com/game1`), first gets an "intro" screen, then the game screen, and finally a fail or success screen.

I'm trying to figure out the most optimal way to do this. Below is the code that works just fine, but I'm looking for more elegant and scale-able solution. Any suggestions?

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

// Import views and components
import Step1 from "../Intro/Step1";
import StatusBar from "../../components/StatusBar/StatusBar";
import Game1 from "./Games/Game1/Game1";
import Game2 from "./Games/Game2/Game2";
import Intro from "./Intro/Intro";
import Password from "./Password/Password";
import Success from "./Success/Success";
import Fail from "./Fail/Fail";
import FailBeginOnStart from "./Fail/FailBeginOnStart";

// Data

function Game() {
  const data = {
    game1: {
      desc: "some description for game 1",
    },
    game2: {
      desc: "some description for game 2",
    },
  };

  // Get global states from redux toolkit
  const showIntro = useSelector((state) => state.game.showIntro);
  const showSuccess = useSelector((state) => state.game.showSuccess);
  const showFail = useSelector((state) => state.game.showFail);
  const showPassword = useSelector((state) => state.game.showPassword);
  const completedGame = useSelector((state) => state.game.completedGame);
  const selectedLanguage = useSelector((state) => state.game.selectedLanguage);

  // Get current param from URL (example /game1)
  const { game } = useParams();

  // Strip slash to get matching game ID (example game1)
  const gameId = game.replace(/-/g, "");

  const GameScreen = () => {

    // show intro screen
    if (showIntro === true) {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar />
          <Intro path={game} id={gameId} data={data[gameId]} />
        </>
      );
    }

    // show success screen
    if (showSuccess === true) {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar />
          <Success data={data[gameId]} />
        </>
      );
    }

    // show fail screen
    if (showFail === true) {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar />
          <Fail data={data[gameId]} />
        </>
      );
    }

    // Show actual game
    switch (true) {
      case game === "game1":
        return <Game1 data={data[gameId]} />;
      case game === "game2":
        return <Game2 data={data[gameId]} />;
      default:
        return <Step1 />;
    }
  };

  return <GameScreen />;
}

export default Game;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using more dictionaries and fewer `if` and `switch` statements?

Instead of having a bunch of different booleans for `showIntro`, `showSuccess`, etc. you can have a string value for `currentScreen` and use that as a property key to get the correct screen.

*You could also potentially handle this part of it by using `react-router-dom`.  That may be cleaner, but it would involve storing more into in the URL, like `www.name.com/game1/intro`.*

Right now it looks like they all take the same `data` object which is great!  The `path` and `id` are only required by `Intro` but we might as well pass them down to all of the screens.

We can store the mapping of game to component alongside the mapping of game to description to avoid the hacky `switch (true) {` statement.

```
// Configuration
const gameDataMapping = {
    game1: {
      desc: "some description for game 1",
      component: Game1
    },
    game2: {
      desc: "some description for game 2",
      component: Game2
    },
  };

// Renders the correct component for the game id.
function Play({ id, data }) {
  const Component = gameDataMapping[id]?.component;
  if (Component) {
    return <Component data={data}/>; // Could pass down id and path here.
  }
  return <Step1/>; // or an error message?
}

// Map from game state to component.
const screenMapping = {
  intro: Intro,
  success: Success,
  fail: Fail,
  play: Play
}

function Game() {

  // Get global states from redux toolkit
  const completedGame = useSelector((state) => state.game.completedGame);
  const selectedLanguage = useSelector((state) => state.game.selectedLanguage);
  const currentScreen = useSelector((state) => state.game.currentScreen);

  // Get current param from URL (example /game1)
  const { game } = useParams();

  // Strip slash to get matching game ID (example game1)
  const gameId = game.replace(/-/g, "");

  const Screen = screenMapping[currentScreen];

  const data = gameDataMapping[gameId];

  if (!data) {
    // TODO: return some "game not found" screen;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {currentScreen === 'play' ? null : <StatusBar />}
      <Screen path={game} id={gameId} data={data[gameId]}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

That was my first attempt, but it still feels like we are doing too much routing in the component.  My train of thought is: can we create a [route object](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) for each game?  We need a `path` and an `element`.  We would want some sort of wrapper around the individual game components (`Game1`, etc.) to apply the `Intro`, `Success`, and `Fail` screens to each.

I'm also wondering if it makes more sense to have a `GameDataContext` which the screen components can access rather than passing down props?

Here's how that might look:

```
const GameDataContext = createContext();

// Use this in your components.
export const useGameData = useContext(GameDataContext);

// Wraps the 'play' element with alternate views and a data provider.
function Game({ play, data }) {
  const currentScreen = useSelector((state) => state.game.currentScreen);

  return (
    <GameDataContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
      {currentScreen === 'play' ? null : <StatusBar />}
      {{ // Map from game state to element.
        intro: <Intro />,
        success: <Success />,
        fail: <Fail />,
        play: play
      }[currentScreen]}
    </GameDataContext.Provider>
  )
}

// Render the correct component and data for each game using react-router v6.
export default function App() {
  const element = useRoutes([
    {
      index: true,
      element: <Home />
    }, {
      path: 'game-1',
      element: (
        <Game
          data={{ desc: "some description for game 1" }}
          play={<Game1 />}
        />
      )
    }, {
      path: 'game-2',
      element: (
        <Game
          data={{ desc: "some description for game 2" }}
          play={<Game2 />}
        />
      )
    }
  ]);

  return element;
}
```